R3F - Get loading progress of Splat
I created a scene within a Splat. For Controls I'm using the Floating Capsule Player Controller from DREI. Sometimes the Player fall through the ground, especially on weaker PCs.
Therfore I want to pause Physics, until the Splat is fully loaded, but I couldn't find a callback function like onLoad() or something similar.
In the Splat.tsx I could found the usage of useLoader, but my React Skills are not good enough, to find out, how I could use this.
Does someone know, how to get the progress from Splat component, when loading the .splat file?
My project: https://3dgs-research.vercel.app/
<Splat  
    renderOrder={2} 
    src={'./path/to/my.splat'} 
    onLoad={() => setSplatLoaded(true)} // Does not exist
  />
{splatLoaded && (
 <Physics timeStep="vary">
  <Floor renderOrder={1} />
  <Player
    renderOrder={3}
    position={[0, 1, 0]}
    cameraPos={{ x: 0, y: 0 }}
    mode={'CameraBasedMovement'}
  />
</Physics>
)}

Floor.jsx:
<RigidBody type="fixed">
        <mesh
          renderOrder={renderOrder}
          position={[0, -0.25, 0]}
          ref={floor}
          receiveShadow={true}>
          <boxGeometry args={[50, 0.5, 50]} />
          <meshStandardMaterial color="#D9CABD" opacity={0} transparent={true} />
        </mesh>
      </RigidBody>

